# app.config Xamarin pcl

Tags: binding, configuration, xamarin.forms, app-config

I need to add some tag in a app.config file for implement a dll (xmlsoccer).
I have to add something like

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
```

in a configuration node, but I don't know where it is.
I tried to create an app.config file and set DotNetConfig.xsd as scheme, but during compile, I have this errors:

- WARNING: failed to load endpoint configuration for *
- SyStem.InvalidOperationException: A Binding must be configured for this channel factory

can anyone help me?

I tried to write this:

`    public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx");

```
    App application;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);         
        // LoadApplication(new App(binding, EndPoint));
        CreateBasicHttp();
        LoadApplication(application);
    }

    private  void CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000,
        };
        binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483646,
            MaxStringContentLength = 5242880,
        };
        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;      
        application = new App(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx"));
    }`
```

in my MainActivity.cs, but obviously it isn't enough.

Comment: Xamarin mobile apps don't use app.config files.

Comment: Perfect -_-
So, any suggestion about what I can do for solve the problem?

Comment: from what you've posted I have no idea what you actually need to do in the app.config.  If it's just bindings for a WCF service that can be done programatically.

Comment: Can't I use AndroidManifest.xml for this scope?

Answer (score -1):

Still looking for answer?
Take a look here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19303/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-xamarin-forms-pcl

Steps:

1.- Opening a command prompt in Windows and using the SLSvcUtil.exe tool
from the Silverlight SDK to generate a proxy from a WSDL file. slsvcutil http://www.yourserver.com/WebServices/YourServiceSoapClient.asmx?WSDL     /out:YourService.cs That utility is located at C:\Program Files     (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools\ on my computer.

2.- Adding the resulting YourService.cs file to my project.

3.- Adding the following code to access the service:

```
   // Create the WCF client (created using SLSvcUtil.exe on Windows)
   YourServiceSoapClient client = new YourServiceSoapClient(
      new BasicHttpBinding(),
      new EndpointAddress("hhttp://www.yourserver.com/WebServices/YourServiceSoapClient.asmx"));

   // Call the proxy - this should use the async versions
   client.ServiceFunctionCompleted += OnGotResult;
   client.ServiceFunctionAsync(parameter);
```

And the OnGotResult function:

```
void OnGotResult(object sender, ServiceFunctionCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        string error = null;
        if (e.Error != null)
            error = e.Error.Message;
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            error = "Cancelled";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", error, "OK", "Cancel");
        }
        else
        {
            resultsLabel.Text = e.Result;
        }
    });
}
```